# Reusing an Array, but odd out come

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm just trying to create a very simple game with HTML5 and JS, now at the moment I have a ship that can fire a bullet. If you hold the spare bar the bullet is moved correctly and works fine. But if you press space bar in the middle of a shot, it will create a new bullet but the speed will be like doubled. Here is the code

```
function Bullet(x,y)
{
this.xPos = x; 
this.yPos = y; 
this.speed = 5; 
this.alive = true;
this.lifeTimer = 0;
}

tempBullet = new Bullet( -100, -100);
bullets[0] = tempBullet;

if (32 in keysDown && player.fired == false) //space
{ 
    //Create new bullet
    var bulletDone = false;
    player.fired = true;
    player.firedTimer = 1;
    tempBullet = new Bullet( player.xPos + 14, player.yPos);
    for( i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++ )
    {
        if( bullets[i].alive == false )
        {
            bulletDone = true;
            bullets[i] = tempBullet;
        }
    }

    if( bulletDone == false )
    {
        bullets[bullets.length] = tempBullet;
    }
}

if( player.firedTimer >= 1 )
{
    player.firedTimer++;
}

if( player.firedTimer >= 60 )
{
    player.firedTimer = 0;
    player.fired = false;
}
```

These are code snippets, the rest is stuff that would just get in the way. Am I re-using the old assets in my bullets array wrongly?

Cheers for the help and read

Comment: Could you please explain your motivation to create `bullets[0] = new Bullet( -100, -100);` (on every game loop iteration I guess)? And what's that `.alive` logic?

Comment: the bullets[0] = new Bullet( -100, -100); is only called once, and that is when the page is loaded. if it is alive, then draw, if not then don't

Comment: And you're not drawing them by replacing them with `tempBullet`? Or do you want to remove them from the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> tempBullet = new Bullet( player.xPos + 14, player.yPos);
> ```

Please use local variables, you seem to have forgotten to [declare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) the `var tempBullet`. Not the cause of you problem though I guess.

> ```
> for ( i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++ )
>     if( bullets[i].alive == false ) {
>         bulletDone = true;
>         bullets[i] = tempBullet;
>     }
> ```

Notice that in this loop you are reassigning all dead bullets to *the same* `tempBullet`. That means when you iterating over the `bullets` collection to animate (move) all of them, you will visit the `tempBullet` multiple times. When you're increasing its position each time, this will sum up and result in the unnormal speed.

To fix that, create new bullet objects every time you want to replace a dead bullet:

```
var bulletDone = false;
for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++ ) {
    if ( ! bullets[i].alive ) {
        bulletDone = true;
        bullets[i] = new Bullet( player.xPos + 14, player.yPos);
    }
}

if ( ! bulletDone ) {
    bullets.push( new Bullet( player.xPos + 14, player.yPos) );
}
```

Comment: I just added var infront of the tempBullet, but the speed still speeds up